# What is the state of the art in terms of local atomic environment descriptors for machine learning?

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning

A lot of atomistic machine learning deals with correctly describing atomic neighborhood environments by vectors or fingerprints (see, e.g. [*J. Chem. Phys.* 149, 244102 (**2018**)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5055772), [*Phys. Rev. B* 87, 184115 (**2013**)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.87.184115)), before feeding those descriptions to neural networks, kernel ridge regressors or other algorithms

So the question is: **what is the current status of local atomic environment descriptors for machine learning?**
Specifically, I want to know what makes a good descriptor and if there are any classification to them (i.e., what makes them different?).

(This question is complimentary to ["What is the current status of machine learning applied to materials or molecular systems?"](https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/18/63).)

Comment: Are we talking about only man-made descriptors or including deep learning solutions, too?

Comment: @Greg Anything goes! The only ones I know at the moment are the ones implemented in [AMP](https://amp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/theory.html#descriptor). All three seem to apply some heuristics as to how an atom "sees" its environment.

By deep-learning descriptor, you mean a neural network that "learned" to how classify local atomic environments? If so, this is interesting, and I didn't know it existed :)

Answer (score 16):

If you are familiar with the [Behler-Parrinello symmetry functions](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3553717) implemented in AMP, you may be interested in seeing how they compare to other atom-centered representations in terms of speed and accuracy. Marcel F. Langer, Alex Goeßmann, and Matthias Rupp have recently released [their benchmarking](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.12081) [efforts](https://github.com/sirmarcel/cmlkit) including the symmetry functions, the [Many-body Tensor Representation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.06439), and the [Smooth Overlap of Atomic Positions representation](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.87.184115). Their work also includes concise summaries of other representations to get you up to speed as well as **what exactly makes a good representation**:

1. Invariance to rotations, translations, and permutations
2. Uniqueness: "Systems with identical representations that differ in property
   introduce errors"
3. Continuity/Differentiability
4. Computational efficiency
5. Structure (e.g constant size)
6. Generality, " in the sense of being able to encode any
   atomistic system"

**What distinguishes many representations is the choice of their basis set** when encoding physical distances and angles into machine-learning inputs. Where the Behler-Parrinello symmetry functions use Gaussian functions, the [Artrith-Urban-Ceder descriptor](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.96.014112) uses Chebyshev polynomials. The Many-Body Tensor Representation uses a real-space basis, while the Smooth Overlap of Atomic Positions uses spherical harmonics. Michele Ceriotti's group has released [an excellent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.00408.pdf) connecting these atom-centered representations with a general mathematical formulism.

Dr. Ceriotti is also on a paper with Gabor Csanyi where they have extensively investigated the topic of uniqueness. [The paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.11696.pdf) **highlights the limitations of using representations that stop at 3-body terms** (i.e distances and angles).

While invariance and equivariance might be handled by the representation, there are several groups working on finding [**ways to handle equivariance directly with the model architecture**](https://blondegeek.github.io/e3nn_tutorial/). As far as I understand, this is especially necessary when learning tensorial properties rather than scalar properties like energy.

As Greg alluded to, there have also been efforts to create **machine learning frameworks where atomic representations can be learned and tuned automatically**. Schnet (or [Schnetpack](https://schnetpack.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) is a framework that uses continuous-filter convolutional neural networks to do so.

I recommend watching these lectures from the recent Institute for Pure and Applied Mathematics program on "Machine Learning for Physics and the Physics of Learning":

Richard G. Hennig: [Machine-learning for materials and physics discovery through symbolic regression and kernel methods](http://www.ipam.ucla.edu/abstract/?tid=16352&pcode=MLPWS1)

Tess Smidt: [Euclidean Neural Networks* for Emulating Ab Initio Calculations and Generating Atomic Geometries *also called Tensor Field Networks and 3D Steerable CNNs](http://www.ipam.ucla.edu/abstract/?tid=16346&pcode=MLPWS1)

Anatole von Lilienfeld: [Quantum Machine Learning](http://www.ipam.ucla.edu/abstract/?tid=15761&pcode=MLPWS2)

Michele Ceriotti: [Machine learning for atomic and molecular simulations](http://www.ipam.ucla.edu/abstract/?tid=15817&pcode=MLPWS4)

Matthias Rupp: [How to assess scientific machine learning models? Prediction errors and predictive uncertainty quantification](http://www.ipam.ucla.edu/abstract/?tid=15782&pcode=MLPWS4)

Gabor Csanyi: [Representation and regression problems for molecular structure and dynamics](http://www.ipam.ucla.edu/abstract/?tid=15837&pcode=MLPWS4)

Comment: Excellent answer @Stephen! An extra +1 for the IPAM links!

Comment: @StephenXie can you join this? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107323/materials-modeling

Comment: It is a very nice summary of the different directions of research and concise, useful comparison of differences.